# Loading csv file fails to load in js file for public assets using play framework with scala

Tags: playframework

In Play framework for scala I'm using data.csv in the js file line_graph.js and line_graph.js is loaded but data.csv is not getting loaded. How shall i load data in js file.

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("js/line_graph.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <a  href="@routes.Assets.at("js/data.csv")"></a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.js"></script>
```

My assets structure.

public
   /js
     /line_graph.js
     ,data.csv

my routes

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

application.conf

```
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src *; script-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com code.jquery.com"
```

line_graph.js code

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error)
        throw error;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.number = d.number;
        d.iteration1 = +d.iteration1, d.iteration2 = +d.iteration2;
    });
```

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser developper window ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/data.csv not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file `line_graph.js` you don't use the correct url for the csv file. Try with:

```
d3.csv("/assets/js/data.csv", function(error, data) {
  ...
```